# Cannot write create file using PHP file_put_contents

Tags: php, file, file-permissions

I'm new at the whole php thing, and I need to write a file in the server (my own computer where I am developing a web app) with some config info. Here is the code I'm using:

```
  $filename = "config.conf";
  $db_info = $db_user . "<-*->" . $db_passwd . "<-*->" . $db_name;
  if (file_put_contents($filename,$db_info) === false){
      $ret["error"]  = "Can't create/write: $filename.";
      mysqli_close($con);
      echo json_encode($ret);
      return;   
  }
```

When I test my web app I get the create/write error I wrote. I checked and the file is not created. My working directory is in /var/www/tests however I've checked tests and my user has read and write permissions and is owner of that folder. If I create a file with a ordinary file explorer I have no problems whatsoever. Since the function is so simple, I am at a loss. Please help!

Comment: Your user seems to have the appropriate permissions but, does your user run PHP as well? In many web server set-ups it isn't the case.

Comment: The PHP process is probably not running as your user. It probably runs within the Apache process, and therefor inherits the rights of the user that runs the Apache daemon (httpd). (If you are using Apache, that is).

Comment: The user that php is running under needs read/write permissions. So if it's running as apache or apache2 or httpd or whatever, that's the user that needs write access.

Comment: generally its www-data in linux when used along with apache

Comment: That conf format you have going on looks like a royal pain, also. You should store it in something a bit more portable, like JSON. Or use an array to ini library to write and parse_ini_file to read.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I just wanted to use some separator string that I knew would not be used for a username or such. But I'll look into that parse ini file function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does web server has read/write permissions (e.g. nginx uses www-data user)? try setting permissions to 777 for folder where you want to create that file.

Comment: Ok, so I created a new group and added myself and the www-data user. There was no error, but now I don't know where the file was created. I thought it would be created in the current folder, but this was not the case. However the question is answered